# How to hide devexpress ribbonControl bar items on WinForms

Tags: winforms, devexpress, toolbar, ribbon, ribbon-control

I want to hide the [DevExpress RibbonControl](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2500) bar items (i know how to hide the page but not the pageGroup and items) based on user's criteria. However, i felt to find the right property to do that. I'm kindly asking for your helping hand.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Please use the [BarItem.Visibility](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarItem_Visibilitytopic) and [RibbonPageGroup.Visible](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonPageGroup_Visibletopic) properties:

```
barButtonItem1.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemVisibility.Never;
//...
ribbonPageGroup1.Visible = false;
```

Comment: sorry, can you give me an example or something?

Comment: @user758961: Example of using this properties??? It is not quite clear to me, how can you run into a problem when using these properties?  Anyway, see the updated answer.

Comment: @user758961: "...It helped"  -
Don't use a words, but accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
RibbonControl.Minimized = true
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/266816/How-to-collapse-expand-ribbon-using-code-in-Devexp